# Python Discord Bot Tiktok Code not working

Tags: python, api, tiktok

the following code just not work. If i type in the command in discord it just nothing happens, but the bot is marked as online. I am running th ebot on replit.com

Here is my code:

```
import os
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from tiktokpy import TikTokPy

# Discord bot setup
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# TikTokPy setup
api = TikTokPy()

# Discord command
@bot.command(name='trendingvids')
async def trendingvids(ctx):
    print('Executing trendingvids command...')
    try:
        # Fetch the trending videos from TikTok API
        trending = api.trending(count=5)

        # Filter the videos with #dogs and #cats hashtags
        filtered = [video for video in trending if "#dogs" in video['desc'] and "#cats" in video['desc']]

        # Create the response message
        response = ""
        for i, video in enumerate(filtered):
            response += f"{i+1}. {video['desc']} - {video['video']['urls'][0]}\n"

        print('Sending response...')
        # Send the response to the Discord channel
        await ctx.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)
  
# Discord bot token
bot.run('token')
```